# Operator Overloading in C++ as int + obj

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I have following class:-

```
class myclass
{
    size_t st;

    myclass(size_t pst)
    {
        st=pst;
    }

    operator int()
    {
        return (int)st;
    }

    int operator+(int intojb)
    {
        return int(st) + intobj; 
    }

};
```

this works fine as long as I use it like this:-

```
char* src="This is test string";
int i= myclass(strlen(src)) + 100;
```

but I am unable to do this:-

```
int i= 100+ myclass(strlen(src));
```

Any idea, how can I achieve this??

Answer (score 27):

Implement the operator overloading outside of the class:

```
class Num
{
public:
    Num(int i)
    {
        this->i = i;
    }

    int i;
};

int operator+(int i, const Num& n)
{
    return i + n.i;
}
```

Comment: +1. You should prefer the non-member versions anyway, even in cases where it's not necessary. Only use the member variants when you have to.

Comment: I always prefer to befriend my non-member operators.

Answer (score 13):

You have to implement the operator as a **non-member function** to allow a primitive int on the left hand side.

```
int operator+( int lhs, const myclass& rhs ) {
    return lhs + (int)rhs;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answers here will solve the problem, but the following is the pattern I use when I'm doing this:

```
class Num
{
public:
  Num(int i)       // Not explicit, allows implicit conversion to Num
  : i_ (i)
  {
  }

  Num (Num const & rhs)
  : i_ (rhs.i_)
  {
  }

  Num & operator+= (Num const & rhs)  // Implement +=
  {
    i_ += rhs.i_;
    return *this;
  }

private:
    int i_;
};

//
// Because of Num(int), any number on the LHS or RHS will implicitly
// convert to Num - so no need to have lots of overloads
Num operator+(Num const & lhs, Num const & rhs)
{
  //
  // Implement '+' using '+='
  Num tmp (lhs);
  tmp+=rhs;
  return tmp;
}
```

One of the key benefits of this approach is that your functions can be implemented in terms of each other reducing the amount of overall code you need.

**UPDATE:**

To keep performance concerns at bay, I would probably define the non member operator+ as an inline function something like:

```
inline Num operator+(Num lhs, Num const & rhs)
{
  lhs+=rhs;
  return lhs;
}
```

The member operations are also inline (as they're declared in the class body) and so in all the code should be very close to the cost of adding two raw `int` objects.

Finally, as pointed out by jalf, the consequences of allowing implicit conversions in general needs to be considered.  The above example assumes that it's sensible to convert from an integral type to a 'Num'.

Comment: But there's no guarantee that converting from int is a meaningful operation. And the implicit conversation may be inefficient compared to just defining `operator+(int, Num)`

Comment: @jalf:  Caveat for the conversion added.  Regarding the implicit conversion, if the functions are inline then a good compiler should produce identical code for the above as it does for the (int, Num) case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my question is: in the operator+= you give that the input is an object of type Num, but how about if I want to add an integer? (my g++ says I need to put an object as input)

Comment: @Tomer: What example are you testing with?

Answer (score 2):

You need a global function operator+( int, myclass ) to do this:

```
int operator+( int intobj, myclass myobj )
{ return intobj + int(myobj); }
```

Comment: With argument-dependent lookup, it shouldn't have to be global.