# Overloading operator order

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator Overloading in C++ as int + obj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188566/operator-overloading-in-c-as-int-obj)
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) [c++-faq](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq)

I have a `Point` object with this operator:

```
Point operator +(float other) const {
  return Point(x + other, y + other, z + other);
}
```

I can perform addition like so:

```
point + 10
```

But I can't perform it in reverse order:

```
10 + point
```

Is there another operator I need to overload in order to provide this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normally want to overload the *global* operator:

```
Point operator+(Point const &a, float b);
Point operator+(float a, Point const &b);
```

Instead of two overloads, you may want to use only one overload:

```
Point operator+(Point const &a, Point const &b);
```

and then have a ctor to create a Point from a float:

```
class Point { 
    public:
        Point(float);
};
```

In this case, adding a float to a Point will use the ctor to convert the float to a Point, then use your overloaded operator+ to add those two Points together.

Comment: Indeed.  But many (e.g. Meyers) would argue that implicit conversion constructors can lead to issues...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: they certainly *can* lead to some issues, but when you look carefully, they arise most often when you convert from class to basic type. From basic type to class *tends* to be a lot safer (though it certainly *can* still raise issues).

Comment: Especially in this case: `point + 10` is already combining the mathematical notions of vector and scalar values, by allowing the user to write `10` in place of `point_offset(10,10,10)` (note that a point and a vector value are also slightly different - vectors can be used to denote points relative to an origin, but not all vectors *are* points and it's mathematically meaningless to "add two points together"). If you're going to combine those concepts anyway, then to me it makes sense to allow that implicit conversion. If you're not going to combine them, don't allow `Point + float` either.

Answer (score 2):

As a free function:

```
Point operator+(float other, const Point &pt) {
    return pt+other;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given an existing `Point& Point::operator+=(float other)`, add these two free functions:

```
Point operator+(Point pt, float other) {
  return pt += other;
}
Point operator+(float other, Point pt) {
  return pt += other;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Outside of the class:

```
inline Point operator+(const float& other, const Point& pnt) { return Point(...); };
```