# C++ operator overloading order

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, overriding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator Overloading in C++ as int + obj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188566/operator-overloading-in-c-as-int-obj)

I override the * operator as following:

```
Point Point::operator *(float scale){
    Point point(this->x*scale, this->y*scale);
    return point;
}
```

How can I fix this:

```
Point p1 (5.0, 10.0);
Point p2 = p1*4; //works fine
Point p3 = 4*p1  //error: no match for 'operator*'
```

Comment: Look at my (virtually identical) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651954/overloading-operator-order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a free function, like this:

```
Point operator *(float scale, Point p)
{
    return p * scale;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You overload the operator as a free function and provide both the versions of it instead of overloading it as member function.

```
Point operator *(float scale, Point p);
Point operator *(Point p, float scale);
```

With these:

1st version supports:

```
Point p3 = 4*p1;
```

and 2nd version supports:

```
Point p2 = p1*4;
```

Comment: I had a duplicate question and you answered the same thing to mine :P