# How do I overload the addition operator to preform commutative calculation?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator Overloading in C++ as int + obj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188566/operator-overloading-in-c-as-int-obj)

I have a class `A` with an overloaded `operator+`. My problem is that I wish to be able to use summation in the two following ways.

```
A a;

a + 5;
```

and

```
5 + a;
```

How do I overload `+` to be able to do this? I am aware that we can overload `++` to perform both post and pre increment (`++x` and `x++`), so how can I simulate the above ability as well?

Comment: You should look into an operator overloading article or reference for the latter. You can find just about everything [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define the operator as a non-member:

```
class A
{
   int operator + (int x) const
   { 
       return 42;
   }
};

inline int operator + (int x, const A& a)
{
   return a+x;  //calls a.operator +(x)
}
```

The `inline` is there to prevent defining the symbol multiple times in case you define the operator in a header.