# Order of operands in overloaded operators?

Tags: python, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I have implemented a class `TimeWindow`, which overloads `__add__`, `__sub__` and `__contains__`.

These operations handle instances of `TimeWindow, int, float` and return instances of `TimeWindow` when appropriate.

Now, I understand that the `+`, `-` and `in` operators when encountering `foo + other` will invoke the proper functions when `foo` is an instance of `TimeWindow` and will fail when `int` or `float` are the first argument as the operation is unsupported by an `int` or `float` type.

My current solution is:

1. Convert `int` and `float` types to equivalent `TimeWindow` type before the operation.
2. Ensure the first argument is `TimeWindow` type when possible.

I know of solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188566/operator-overloading-in-c-as-int-obj) in other languages. Is there an equivalent solution to this in python?

Comment: Do you know about [reflected operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)? If `a.__add__(b)` returns `NotImplemented`, Python will attempt to call `b.__radd(a)__`. Likewise for other binary operator methods.

Comment: @Brian: Gee, and I always thought that `r` prefix stood for "reversed". ;¬)